# Downloading application from weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have requirement for testing a j2ee application which is deployed in a weblogic server.
I have to get the ear add my testclasses into that and depoly it back.

Since weblogic server takes so much memory , I want to run my testcases to run in another box , connect to the weblogic server and download the ear from there and modify and deploy it back.

I know that it is possible to remotely deploy application in weblogic. 
But is it possible to download the application from weblogic ? using JMX ?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks
J

Comment: Is it not possible to build a fresh EAR with the latest source and test classes - and upload it to the server?

Comment: Nope. I have to modify the ear and have to update it . Kind of hot patch , without bringing down the server .

Answer (score 1):

JMX is for the runtime configuration and management (Java Management Extensions). What you're looking for is much simpler - On the WebLogic console, go to the deployments and click on the application of interest.

Next, figure out what the path of the deployed application is and then manually copy (scp if you're in UNIX) the ear file over to your local directory.

If you don't have access to the hosting server then it's not possible to download the app.